# Showing app updation Dialog Box every time whenever user opens the app

Tags: android

**I am using AppUpdater library for Android to notify the user through a dialog box that a new version is avaliable. 
All i want that everytime user opens the app dialog box will appear every time until user update to latest version.**

```
AppUpdater appUpdater = new AppUpdater(this)
                                .setDisplay(Display.DIALOG)
                                .setUpdateFrom(UpdateFrom.XML)
                                .setUpdateXML("https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/sensortest-7881e.appspot.com/o/appupdater.xml?alt=media&token=c75bd1f6-5d65-4414-9199-26ab05f7d0f2")
                                .showEvery(5)
                                .setTitleOnUpdateAvailable("Update Avaliable")
                                .setContentOnUpdateAvailable("Check out the latest version available")
                                .setButtonUpdate("Update now")
                                .setButtonUpdateClickListener(new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Update Button Clicked",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                    }
                                })
                                .setButtonDismiss("Maybe later")
                                .setButtonDismissClickListener(new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                        //dialog.dismiss();
                                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Maybe Latter",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                    }
                                })
                                .setButtonDoNotShowAgain(null)
                                .setIcon(R.drawable.ic_system_update_white_24dp)
                                .setCancelable(false);
        appUpdater.start();
```

Answer (score 0):

Put your code inside a function like:

```
public void checkForUpdates(){
AppUpdater appUpdater = new AppUpdater(this)
                                .setDisplay(Display.DIALOG)
                                .setUpdateFrom(UpdateFrom.XML)
                                .... .... .. .. ... .. .
}
```

Then call checkForUpdates(); on the "OnResume" method, and it will work ;)

Comment: Thanx for the feedback. Solution is to remove only

.showEvery(5)